# Disable click in parent button in Magento Navigation Menu

Tags: magento, redirect, menu

I am looking a way to disable clicking of a Parent category Button in Magento Navigation Menu.
I found lot of examples on how disable "all parent first level" clicking buttons, but not just for one category button.
I tryed with url rewrite without success.
Any idea on how achive this ?

Comment: Disable links means not redirect to any where?

Comment: Right, remove the link or make the link do nothing as using a #.
I tryed also using a str_replace('category.html','#'); in Navigation.php but didn't work.
I was expection http://www.mydomain.com/category.html to become http://www.mydomain.com/#

Comment: Did you flush the cache?

Comment: Cache is disabled. Shell i flush it anyway?

Comment: did u check in the function protected function _renderCategoryMenuItemHtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the `Navigation.php`

```
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation
```

change as below.

```
protected function _renderCategoryMenuItemHtml($category, $level = 0, $isLast = false, $isFirst = false,
        $isOutermost = false, $outermostItemClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '', $noEventAttributes = false)
    {
...
if($level==0){
        $html[] = '<a href="#"'.$linkClass.'>';
        $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
        $html[] = '</a>';
        }else{
        $html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';
        $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
        $html[] = '</a>';
    }

 ...
}
```

Flush cache after that

Comment: I am not sure, but i think that this code will affect all level 0 button links. I am trying to have just one of the buttons of the menu not to link. I will need others buttons to keep working. That's way i toughth about usig a str_replace, so that i can hit just that url.

Comment: U can have a check for  category id then and str_replace is not a solution

Comment: At the moment i found this solution


if ($child->hasChildren() && $childLevel == 0) {   $html.= '<a href="#" ' . $outermostClassCode . ' onclick="return false;"><span>'
        . $this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) . '</span></a>'."\n";
    }
    else {
        $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>'
        . $this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) . '</span></a>';
    }

But i am not able to add a category check in the if istance.

Comment: This solution is working cause is keeping enable links for buttons without sub-categories, but it will be better to choose which category id to set.
I edit app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.phtml cause i have Mage 1.8